# How to remove last request parameter of the URL from Nginx

Tags: nginx, regex

I am new to Nginx, I am having one request URL coming with Token request parameter along with some other request pram. I just want to remove that Token parameter from the URL if its present.

below is the example of the URL :

```
www.xyx.com?abc=234&xy1=456&token=weqewq32243479
```

I am not sure how many request param will come in the URL but it is sure token param will always be in the last

after removing the token it should look like this

```
www.xyx.com?abc=234&xy1=456
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Something like this: `if ($request_uri ~ ^(.*)&token=[a-z0-9]+$) { return 301 $1; }`

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks it's worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, everyone for the response here is the solution for my problem :

```
    if ($request_uri ~ ^(.*)&token=[a-z0-9]+$) {
                 return 301 $1; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you give this a try?

```
      if ($args ~ "(.*)&?token=[a-z0-9]+$" ) {
        set $args  $1;
      }
```